# Celery status stuck in pending status

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task, celerybeat, celeryd

I found a example for running celery with mongodb as the backend result here [original code example](http://skillachie.com/2013/06/15/intro-celery-and-mongodb/). In his example he has CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE with some parameters to run every minute, in my case i just commented out this code. In my case I just want to run the task as soon as it is received. From the worker log I don't even see the task is received and the output for result.status is PENDING. Why is this staying in the pending status and not completing the task. Its a simple addition task so I cant image it would take a long time.

One other thing is I have virtual environment so from what was told to me is I should run celery as such "**celery multi start worker --loglevel=info**"

I am new to celery and this is a little confusing to me. Thanks in advance for any help.

**celeryconfig.py file**

```
# from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "mongodb"
CELERY_MONGODB_BACKEND_SETTINGS = {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 27017,
    "database": "jobs", 
    "taskmeta_collection": "stock_taskmeta_collection",
}

# this was part of the original code but i commented out in hopes 
# it would run the task right away and not delay.
#
#used to schedule tasks periodically and passing optional arguments 
#Can be very useful. Celery does not seem to support scheduled task but only periodic
# CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
#     'every-minute': {
#         'task': 'tasks.add',
#         'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),
#         'args': (1,2),
#     },
# }
```

**tasks.py file**

```
from celery import Celery
import time 

#Specify mongodb host and datababse to connect to
BROKER_URL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/jobs'

celery = Celery('EOD_TASKS',broker=BROKER_URL)

#Loads settings for Backend to store results of jobs 
celery.config_from_object('celeryconfig')

@celery.task
def add(x, y):
    time.sleep(5)
    return x + y



# starting celery
celery multi start worker --loglevel=info
celery multi v4.1.0 (latentcall)
> Starting nodes...
    > worker@lnx-v2: OK
```

## running celery task

```
lnx-v2:171> python
Python 3.4.1 (default, Nov 12 2014, 13:34:48) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from tasks import add
>>> result = add.delay(1,1)
>>> result
<AsyncResult: 8e6ee263-d8a4-4b17-8d7a-9873b6c98473>
>>> result.status
'PENDING'
```

## worker log

```
lnx-v2:208> tail -f worker.log
[2017-10-26 13:41:15,658: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2017-10-26 13:41:15,683: INFO/MainProcess] worker@lnx-v2 ready.
[2017-10-26 13:45:50,465: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2017-10-26 13:45:50,487: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2017-10-26 13:45:51,522: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2017-10-26 13:45:51,540: INFO/MainProcess] worker@lnx-v2 ready.
[2017-10-26 13:47:13,169: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2017-10-26 13:47:13,191: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2017-10-26 13:47:14,228: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2017-10-26 13:47:14,254: INFO/MainProcess] worker@lnx-v2 ready.


# Celery process
lnx-v2:209> ps -ef | grep celery
15096     1  0 13:47 ?        00:00:00 [celeryd: worker@lnx-v2:MainProcess] -active- (worker --loglevel=info --logfile=worker%I.log --pidfile=worker.pid --hostname=worker@lnx-v2)
15157 15096  0 13:47 ?        00:00:00 [celeryd: worker@lnx-v2:ForkPoolWorker-1]
```

Comment: DId you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

See if the add method is listed in celery tasks from the following code

```
celery.tasks.keys()
```

I think the decorator you have to close with parenthesis

```
@celery.task()
def add(x, y):
    time.sleep(5)
    return x + y
```